# Jquery ad image into div using base64 code

Tags: jquery, ajax, base64

there is a div for an image, through ajax request I received base64 code for image. the I need to decode and display the image in particular div...

```
<div id="preview" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></div>

$.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data: customerJson,
    dataType: "",
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```

the response data is base64 code

Answer (score 0):

You can change `background-image` css property using jQuery `.css` function as following:

```
$("#preview").css("background-image", "url('data:image/png;base64," + data + "')");
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ck8rpptn/1/

Comment: image is not fit into the div, is displays a part of a image

Comment: you can change the css height and width properties, same as you changed the background-image property: $("#preview").css("width", "500px").css("height", "732px");

Comment: can I have help for convert that image to thumbnail